# Pedir confirmación al imprimir PDF jquery datatables

Tags: html, jquery, datatables, plugin, table

tengo una tabla a la cual le aplico las funcionalidades de el plugin de jquery llamado: jquery datatables, una de las funciones de este plugin es poder generar un PDF de la tabla.

Mi pregunta es, puedo mostrar un mensaje de confirmación al momento de presionar el botón de generar PDF?

Por ejemplo

```
const res = confirm('Desea generar el PDF');

if (res) {
    generarPDF();
}
```

El código que tengo es

```
    $('#tabla').DataTable({
        searching: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        order: [[0, 'desc']],
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 9,
            searchable: false,
            orderable: false
        }],
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                text: 'PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
                title: ``,
                filename: `Reporte entradas ${new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, "-")}  hora ${formatAMPM(new Date)}`,
                messageBottom: `\n\n\nReporte entradas ${new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, "-")}  hora ${formatAMPM(new Date)}`,
                customize: function (doc) {
                    doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 13;
                    doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'center';
                    doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 13;
                },
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
                }
            }
        ],
        pageLength: 5,
        "language": {
            "url": "assets/datatables/Spanish.json"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar el método confirm:

```
if (confirm("¿Desea Generar El PDF?")) {
        generarPDF();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

O también puedes usar una modal de confirmación:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="mi-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width:40%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">¿Desea Generar El PDF?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal-btn-si">Si</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-no">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Muestras la modal:

```
$("#mi-modal").modal('show');
```

Y en la acción de los botones algo como:

```
$("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function () {
      $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
       generarPDF();
});
$("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function () {
        $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Lo que estoy preguntando es como seria una función llamada "generarPDF", de eso va la pregunta, no tengo la función

Comment: Ya entiendo, ya sabes como generar el PDF? Lo que te falta es descargarlo?

Estas trabajando con un modelo-vista-controlador?

Comment: El PDF se genera perfecto, sale bien, se descarga, estoy usando jquery datatables, el problema no es generar el PDF como tal, es pedir una confirmación para que se genere, se que hay que modificar la libreria jquery datatable pero no se como